# FreeRADIUS behind keepalived virtual IP

Tags: freeradius

I'm having some difficulties implementing this freeradius behind keepalived's virtual IP. I need keepalived because I need redundancy for this two factor authentication server.

Radius handles the 2 factor authentication on a Juniper VPN.
So everything works well until the VPN tries to talk with the radius server on the virtual IP.
VPN sends Access-Request to radius server on the virtual IP set by the keepalived.
Radius replies Access-Challenge with the real IP of the server.
The VPN will drop the connection here so the user won't be able to authenticate.

What should I do to force radius use the virtual IP for it's responses?
Should I change some routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally to use a VIP in this way, you'd use NAT, so the destination IP of the packet is rewritten to the internal IP address of the RADIUS server, and the source IP of the packet would be rewritten to the address of the router.

If you're not able to configure this on the Juniper, and you've found a way of forwarding packets to the RADIUS server with the source/destination IP intact, then you can force FreeRADIUS to use a specific source address when responding.

You'll first need to add the VIP as an IP alias as described here: https://support.kemptechnologies.com/hc/en-us/articles/203861685-Configuring-DSR

You'll then need to add the following snippet to your virtual server config:

```
server {
    post-auth {
        update control {
            Packet-Src-IP-Address := <VIP address>
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure the src address in packets sent out from FreeRADIUS match the VIP.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have a LinOTP virtual server in sites-enabled. I can't acomplish this on Juniper side. Do I still need to set an alias if the keepalived package does all the VIP settings? The packets from Juniper are arriving ok to radius through my VIP. Tried to add in my LinOTP virtual server, in post-auth block the update control with Packet-Src-IP-Address := <VIP address>  but no results. Tcpdump ... IP JUNIPER.18540 > VIP.1812: RADIUS, Access-Request (1), id: 0x13 length: 136
IP REAL_IP.1812 > JUNIPER.18540: RADIUS, Access-Challenge (11), id: 0x13 length: 49

Comment: it is possible that we can't set this variable as of: https://wiki.freeradius.org/config/run_time_variables

Comment: You may need to upgrade to FreeRADIUS 3.0.15

Comment: For future visitors: I upgraded to a version 3.x and FreeRADIUS works behind the VIP out of the box (tested with 3.04 and 3.0.15). Thanks again, Arran!

Comment: Excellent news! Thanks for confirming :) We'll make sure to retain this functionality in the v4.0.x series.